# How to make Spacy's statistical models faster

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am using Spacy's pretrained statistical models such as en_core_web_md. I am trying to find similar words between two lists. While the code is working fine. It takes a lot of time to load the statistical model, each time the code is run.

Here is the code I am using.

How to make the models load faster? 
Is there a way to save the model to the disk ?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
list1 =['mango','apple','tomato','orange','papaya']   
list2 =['mango','fig','cherry','apple','dates']
s_words = []
for token1 in list1:
    list_to_sort = [] 
    for token2 in list2:
        list_to_sort.append((token1, token2, nlp(str(token1)).similarity(nlp(str(token2)))))

    sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key = itemgetter(2), reverse=True)[0][:2]
    s_words.append(sorted_list)
    similar_words= list(zip(*s_words))[1]
```

Comment: Model loading in IO bound. If you want it to go faster load smaller models. You are using `web_md`, which stands for medium- there is also `en_core_web_sm`

Comment: @mbatchkarov Thanks for your answer. But I think I do require medium models at the least. I also tried disable =['parser','ner','tagger']. It definitely speeds up the loading but what if In some case, the user does require parser, ner etc. The model loading by default has to be faster in such a case. I believe disabling is just a hack. Wonder is there a better solution. This was the gist of my question above.

Comment: A spacy model is a large and complex data structure. To make deserialisation faster you need to attack either the large part (by finding a smaller model) or by the complex part (by rewriting spacy or training your own models). Outside of these two options, we'd have to rethink the fundamentals of what you are doing. Here are a few questions. Do you have evidence to suggest you absolutely require at least medium model? Can you compromise on accuracy? Can you preload the models once and query them repeatedly (e.g. a web service/ a jupyter notebook cell)? Do you have a fast SSD?